# Add tab / local task to a node

Tags: 8, routes

I've created a module called `hotel_reviews`.

I've created the route node/{node}/reviews using [hotel_reviews.routing.yml](http://pastebin.com/raw/mmjN28EP).

```
hotel_reviews.content:
  path: '/node/{node}/reviews'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\hotel_reviews\Controller\ReviewsController::content'
    _title: 'Reviews'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```

I then tried to add a local task using [hotel_reviews.links.task.yml](http://pastebin.com/raw/a2nnf7Ks).

```
hotel_reviews.content:
  route_name: hotel_reviews.content
  title: 'Reviews'
  base_route: node.view
  weight: 100
```

I can now access the content defined by my controller at `node/1/reviews`, however when I go to `node/1` I don't see a reviews tab.

What am I doing wrong?

I've been using the following documentation so far:

- [D7 to D8 upgrade tutorial: Convert hook_menu() and hook_menu_alter() to Drupal 8 APIs](https://www.drupal.org/node/2118147)
- [Providing module-defined local tasks](https://www.drupal.org/node/2122253)
- [Structure of routes](https://www.drupal.org/node/2092643)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your base route is wrong. You need to use the route that node uses for /node/1. That's not node.view. It's entity.node.canonical.

Comment: It's similar to what done from the Tracker module in its [tracker.links.task.yml](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21tracker%21tracker.links.task.yml/8.2.x) file for the "Activity" tab (/user/{user}/activity) for which  the base route is  entity.user.canonical. (I added this example as reminder for myself, hoping it will help other users too.)

Comment: This worked great for me. Thanks ... But it's switching away from the admin theme to the front-end theme ... Any thoughts on how to keep it with the admin theme? Thanks!

Comment: Nevermind ... found it ... leaving answer here for others:
(in route definition)
options:
    _admin_route: TRUE