# Why aren't my local tasks shown?

Tags: 8, routes

I have the module.routing.yml as

```
entity.node.ssl_check:  
  path: '/node/{node}/check-ssl'  
  defaults:  
  _form: '\Drupal\ssl_check\Form\SslCheck'  
  _title: 'Check SSL Cert'  
  requirements:  
  _permission: 'access check ssl tab'
```

and module.links.task.yml as

```
 entity.node.ssl_check:  
  route_name: entity.node.ssl_check  
  title: 'Ssl check'  
  base_route: entity.node.canonical  
  weight: 15
```

Here when I access node/1104/check-ssl/ the form defined in the form controller is loading. But my other need that is to show a 'Ssl check' tab when I visit path /node/1104/ is not there. I have done the tab thing while dealing with Controller but not working with form controller. Please help. I have checked '[Add tab / local task to a node](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/199625/add-tab-local-task-to-a-node)' this but there was nothing dealing with form controller.

Comment: The module.routing.yml file you are showing is not well-formed; it misses the indentation for `defaults`.

Comment: Also, as for creating local tasks, there isn't any difference between using a form or a controller: What you put in the .links.task.yml file is the same for both the cases.

Answer (score 2):

Since everything looked just fine in your code, I tried the following in a custom module:

```
#test.links.task.yml
test.node_test:
   title: 'Wooorking'
   route_name: entity.node.canonical
   base_route: entity.node.canonical
```

And this is working like a charm. Also when I added a custom routing, which was pointing to a form controller, it showed up! (although not worked, because I didn't handled the node parameter in the routing configuration)

So the problem lies another where.

So I suggest you to do it step by step way (building your routing and task yml) to understand your problem. Clearing the cache each time when you change something in your YML files. If you found the problem, please post the solution, so also we can learn from this.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, if there's only one task, it won't appear.
You'll watch the links appear if you add 2 or more links.

In other words, this wont appear alone :

```
entity.node.ssl_check:  
  route_name: entity.node.ssl_check  
  title: 'Ssl check'  
  base_route: entity.node.canonical
```

This will show two tabs

```
entity.node.ssl_check:  
  route_name: entity.node.ssl_check  
  title: 'Ssl check'  
  base_route: entity.node.canonical  

entity.node.ssl_check2:  
  route_name: entity.node.ssl_check  
  title: 'Ssl check again'  
  base_route: entity.node.canonical
```

Answer (score 0):

Modified the code as

```
 entity.node.ssl_check:  
      title: Ssl check  
      route_name: entity.node.ssl_check  
      base_route: entity.node.canonical  
      weight: 15
```

Answer (score 0):

I had copied and pasted my code wrong. Things to check:

- The file name is YOUR_MODULE.links.task.yml
- The task name is YOUR_MODULE.some_task
- The route name is YOUR_MODULE.some_route

The last one got me. It appears that if the route does not exist, the local task will silently not show.

---

**File:** *YOUR_MODULE.links.task.yml*

```
YOUR_MODULE.some_task
  title: 'Example Title'  
  route_name: YOUR_MODULE.manual_email
  base_route: YOUR_MODULE.manual_email
```